# Jenkin build failure. running on windows 7 32 bit

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, java-8, build

I am new on jenkins. I have created one job on jenkins under freestyle project. I use `execute windows batch file command` to build project. Under that I wrote `java -version` command and save it. When I build the project it gives me following error.

I used `jdk 1.8.0_291` and `maven 3.8.1`

I face following error:

```
Started by user Bhagyashree Deshmukh
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Users\R&B\.jenkins\workspace\DemoJenkin
[DemoJenkin] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\R&B\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins7315128789469658947.bat
'C:\Users\R' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the path specified.
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Since the message `'C:\Users\R' is not recognized...` may be significant. May you change the `working directory` to the new one that does not contain a special character (`&`) ? e.g. `c:\temp\project`.

Comment: Having a directory or file with "&" in the name (amongst many other characters) is a poor choice. "&" In unix is the "place process into backgroundx indicator. As Jenkins is Unix primary and developed, you are tempting fate. Surprised you could.create a user with that name.